# Can this redirect logic be achieved using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

**Edit:**

So I figured the following: Domains `B.com` and `C.com` A-records point to the new server as well, i.e. the ip. Within `pd-admin` the vhost manager I added those URLs as **Co-Domains** of `A.com`. Doing so, the application should know if `A.com, B.com or C.com` was entered and everything should show website x. **In htaccess, in which variable can I test which of the above URLs was entered and redirect to A.com/b resp. A.com/c?**

---

I'm trying to explain this as easy as possible: Customer has domain `A.com, B.com and C.com`. Each domain has it's own website, i.e. `a, b and c`. Website `a` is being relaunched, the domain's A-record now points to a new web server ip, `website x`.

All working fine so far, the DNS change was done and all old URLs of domain A / website a are now being redirected to it's new urls using simple htaccess.

Now the tricky part:

Domains `B` and `C` and their websites `b` and `c` are supposed to be part of website `x`, like `A.com/b`. So the domains `B` and `C` are now changed to be redirected to **`A.com`**, so if you enter `B.com` you will be redirected to **`A.com/`**. **In the htaccess file, how can I set redirects if the entered URL is `B.com` or `C.com`?**

For instance, an `A.com` redirect looks like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foobar.aspx
RewriteRule . %{HTTP­_HOST}/foobar [R=301,L]
```

Now, for the `B.com` redirects I thought of something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} b/foobar.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} B\.com
RewriteRule . A.com/b/foobar [R=301,L]
```

But it does not seem to work. In the DNS settings `B.com` will be just redirected to `A.com`, but does Apache/ htaccess know `B.com` was entered?

Also `RewriteRule . A.com/b/foobar [R=301,L]` might now work because also `A.de` should work.

Edit: do I have to add Co-Domains `B.com` and `C.com` in the vHost manager for Domain `A.com`?